# Why schnorr signatures uses H(R||m) instead of H(m)?

Tags: schnorr-signature

The Schnorr signature scheme was defined originally as $(c, s)$ such that $sG = R + cX$, and the verification process consisted of computing $R = sG - cX$ and then verifying that $c = H(R||m)$ so using only $H(m)$ would not have worked for verification. However, in the verification process of the Schnorr signature variant $(R, s)$, we first compute $c = H(R||m)$ and then verify that $R = sG - cX$, if we change $c = H(R||m)$ by $c = H(m)$ the verification process is not affected. I guess that using $c = H(m)$ is not secure for the Schnorr scheme, but I wonder why.

**Note:** For example, in the ECDSA scheme $s = k^{-1}(H(m) + dr)$ the hash consists only of $H(m)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second scheme, the signature $(R,s)$ is verified as $R\overset{?}{=} sG-cX$.

If $c$ does not involve $R$, then you could forge a signature by picking a random $s$ value and calculating $R=sG+cX$, where $c=H(m)$. Therefore, it does matter that $c$ is calculated as $c=H(R\mathbin\| m)$.

With ECDSA, the x-coordinate of a point performs the same function as a hash in the Schnorr signature. This is because the x-coordinate is unpredictable. If I give you a random x-coordinate value, you won't be able to efficiently find a scalar value $a$ such that the point $aG$ has that x-coordinate.

You can therefore think of an ECDSA signature as:

$(c,s) = \biggl(H_2(R),\ \frac{H(m)\ +\ H_2(R)x}{r}\biggr)$, where $H_2(P)$ means to extract the x-coordinate of the point P.

It is verified as $c \overset{?}{=} H_2\biggl(\frac{H(m)G\ +\ cX}{s}\biggr)$

As you can see, ECDSA does have a cryptographically secure one-way function  that involves $R$.

Answer (score 2):

The scheme is completely insecure: $c = H(m)$ does not constrain $R, m, X$ in a way that only the owner of the secret key can satisfy.

To forge a signature $(R, s)$, choose an arbitrary $s$, the set $R = sG- cX$. This passes verification for $c = H(m)$ even when we dint know the secret key.

Comment: You might want to answer the obvious followup question: "why then is ECDSA secure??"

Comment: @poncho Oops, I forgot that part of the questions. But the other answer does a good job at answering that part.